# Pytest: difference between "mocker.patch" and "with mocker.patch"

Tags: python, pytest

I wonder what is the difference between:

```
mocker.patch('name')
... # logic
```

and

```
with mocker.patch('name'):
    pass  # logic
```

On the first method, will the function be mocked "forever"? I mean, if there are other tests that will be ran afterwards, will they be affected by the same mock? If not, why should I use the `with` syntax?

Comment: if by "forever" you mean until the end of that test, then yes.

Comment: Hey thanks! Added an elaborated explanation on the question's body :) @Nullman

Comment: Hi, my understanding is that, in both cases, the mock object will not persist beyond the test where the patch happens. The use of a context manager simply offers a teardown step from within the test itself (that is, if you don't want the function to be mocked during the entire test).

Comment: Yeah it seems like it. Thank you! @Laurent